# JSON data not behaving

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, express

I have a review and submit page where I get data from mysql, send it to my handlebars page as JSON, where I parse and display it.

However, when I plug {{data1}} in my script tag it shows up as

```
{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;32&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:&quot;qweqweq&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;sadasd&q
```

where I cant parse it anymore since all the  "  is now  &quot.

However, though it shows up as perfect JSON if I just plug it straight into the handlebars page as {{data1}}

`[{"id":"32","position":"qweqweq","date":"sadasd","howUhear":"advertisement"`.....

Please help steer me in the right direction, thank you.

my index.js

```js
router.get('/jobappsum', authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res){

 const db = require('../db.js');
 const userIDpre = (`req.session.passport.user: ${JSON.stringify(req.session.passport)}`);

 var userID = userIDpre.match(/\d+/)[0];


 db.query("SELECT * FROM Page1 WHERE id = '"+ userID +"'", function(err, results1, field){
  console.log(results1);
    sum1 = JSON.stringify(results1);
   db.query("SELECT * FROM Page2 WHERE id = '"+ userID +"'", function(err, results2, field){
     sum2 = results2; 
     db.query("SELECT * FROM Page3 WHERE id = '"+ userID +"'", function(err, results3, field){ 
      sum3 = results3;
     })  res.render('jobappsum', { 
    data1: sum1,
    data2: sum2,
    data3: sum3 
    });
;
   }); 
  });
});
```

```html
jobappsum.hbs

{{> header }}


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var obj = JSON.parse({{data1}}); 
//{{data1}} " shows up up as &quot and gives me error
obj = obj[0];


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.id + ", " + obj.position;


</script>


{{result}} 

//will show up as the correct JSON
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
res.render('jobappsum', {
```

Your "jobappsum" is meant to output HTML, so it encodes your quotes. It transforms " to &quot ; as you can see. When you display it in your view, you see " as normal, but it's not the " character itself. It's &quot ; and is displayed as " in the browser.

So, you should use a renderer that doesn't HTML escape.

If you don't want something in the output escaped in your view, try:

```
!{data1}
```

or

```
{{{data1}}}
```

within the view.

Or you can use decodeURI() function to unescape the escaped JSON before parsing:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(decodeURI("{{data1}}"));
```

---

If using Swig.js, you can use:

```
{{ data1|json|raw }}
```

Comment: FYI, !{data1} did not work for me. but {{{data1}}} did. But I'll mark your answer as correct for the wonderful explanation tho.